# Get column value based on another columns value

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so if the title made any sense, I have an order form. I want the user to be able to search for their orders by the order number. Then I want to pull any info from that. So

```
ID | Name | Date
01 | John Smith | 12-13-11
```

If I query for an ID of 01, I want to be able to see the name John Smith. How can I do it? This doesn't give me what I want:

```
$name = "SELECT name FROM order WHERE id = '$prof'" . mysql_real_escape_string($prof) . "'";
```

should the name after SELECT be an *? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't because entire query is incorrect. Try to `echo $name;` and execute it in mysql console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM `order` WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($prof) . "'";
```

Note that `order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL and should be surrounded by backticks.

Comment: +1, although even this doesn't match the case between the query and the table structure - but it's hard to know which one is correct...

Comment: That code after trying to echo it gives me this: SELECT name FROM 'order' WHERE id = '000'000'    Shouldn't it be echoing the value?

Comment: @Joseph Torraca: 1. there is a backtick sign ` not a quote ' 2. of course no, read about `mysql_query()` function